# How To record total timing for C++ repetive Iterative function?

Tags: c++, loops, iteration

I have this function prototype code for factorial calculation by iteration
How do I include a timer to produce total time spent for looping 100 times of the function?

> for (unsigned long i=number; i>=1; i--)       result *=i;

My C++ knowledge is barely basic, so not sure if "loop" is correctly mentioned here. 
However, I was hinted to use .

Pls advice

thank you

Comment: FYI, this loop is so small as to probably be completely unmeasurable reliably. Multiplying two numbers one hundred times ought to be measured in terms of CPU cycles, not time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proper C++11 version of some timing logic:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

auto start_time = system_clock::now();

// your loop goes here:
for (unsigned long i=number; i>=1; i--) result *=i;

auto end_time = system_clock::now();
auto durationInMicroSeconds = duration_cast<microseconds>(end_time - start_time);
cout << "Looping " << number << " times took " << durationInMicroSeconds << "microseconds" << endl;
```

Just for sport, here's a simple RAII-based variation:

```
class Timer {
  public:
    explicit Timer(const string& name)
    : name_(name)
    , start_time_(system_clock::now()) {
    }
    ~Timer() {
      auto end_time = system_clock::now();
      auto durationInMicroSeconds = duration_cast<microseconds>(end_time - start_time);
      cout << "Timer: " << name << " took " << durationInMicroSeconds << "microseconds" << endl;
    }
  private:
    string name_;
    system_clock::time_point start_time_;
};
```

Sure, it's a bit more code, but once you have that, you can reuse it fairly efficiently:

```
{  
  Timer timer("loops");
  // your loop goes here:
  for (unsigned long i=number; i>=1; i--) result *=i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for time spent in executing number of looping statements in the program code try making use of `gettimeofday()` as below,

```
#include <sys/time.h>
struct timeval  tv1, tv2;
gettimeofday(&tv1, NULL);
/* Your loop code to execute here */
gettimeofday(&tv2, NULL);
printf("Time taken in execution = %f seconds\n",
    (double) (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000000 +
    (double) (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec));
```

This solution is more towards `C` which can be employed in your case to calculate time spent.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect situation for a lambda.  Honestly I don't know the syntax in C++ but it should be something like this:

```
duration timer(function f) {
  auto start = system_clock::now();
  f();
  return system_clock::now() - start;
}
```

To use it, you wrap your code in a lambda and pass it to the timer.  The effect is very similar to @Martin J.'s code.

```
duration code_time = timer([] () {
  // put any code that you want to time here
}

duration loop_time = timer([] () {
  for (unsigned long i=number; i>=1; i--) {
    result *=i;
  }
}
```